# How to find a specific value in a column and replace it with another value in R

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataset that contains names of classes (i.e., the names are duplicated) such as:

```
Class
ProjectTeam.Branch.Finder
AirPolProj.Classes.Estimate
ProjectTeam.Branch.Finder
com.ib.client.ExecutionFilter
com.ib.client.ExecutionFilter
AirPolProj.Classes.Estimate
```

I want to replace these values to only include the last name in the class:

```
Class
Finder
Estimate
Finder
ExecutionFilter
ExecutionFilter
Estimate
```

Do you have any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` here for a base R option:

```
df$Class <- sub(".*?([^.]+)$", "\\1", df$Class)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df1$Class <- sub(".*[.]","", df1$Class)
```

Comment: I removed my comment, this would work +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Class <- c(
  "ProjectTeam.Branch.Finder",
  "AirPolProj.Classes.Estimate",
  "ProjectTeam.Branch.Finder",
  "com.ib.client.ExecutionFilter",
  "com.ib.client.ExecutionFilter",
  "AirPolProj.Classes.Estimate")

stringr::str_extract(Class,"(?<=\\.)[^.]*$")
```